# Undefined method 'getEntityName' exception symfony2 Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Here is the error:

> Undefined method 'getEntityName'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Here is the Code:

```
security.yml
    providers:
        main:
            mongodb: { class: Acme\LoginBundle\Document\User }


User.mongodb.yml
    Acme\LoginBundle\Document\User:
        repositoryClass: Acme\LoginBundle\Document\Repository\UserRepository
        fields:
        id:
            id: true
        username:
            type: string
            length: 255
        password:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

The user is validated properly in login controller but when redirecting default_target_path it throws this exception.
I am trying Custom User Provider with MongoDB.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Got it solved!! Replaced getEntity with getDocumentName in supportsClass function of UserProvider.

Comment: Nice! You could answer your own question to show that your problem is solved. This also helps other people who run into the same problem ;)